# to set checked values uncheck

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a dropdown:-

```
<select class="select" id="select" multiple="multiple" ng-model="a.NA">
  <option value="1">1</option>
<optgroup label="group">
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

And a checkbox:-

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a.clM.checkbox2" value="option1" ng-disabled="a.NA">
 <label for="a.clM.checkbox2">NA</label>
```

When I check 'NA' checkbox the dropdown is disabled,so no one can check the inner checkboxes of the dropdown.
But if I check anyone of the inner checkboxes first then check NA checkbox the dropdown got disabled but the checked inner checkboxes remains checked.

What I want is if I check the NA checkbox the inner checkboxes got unchecked(if checked).

Comment: There is no checkboxes in dropdown. Which inner checkboxes you are asking for.

Comment: Can you open a plunkr?

Comment: the select dropdown is a jquery plugin which contains ckeckboxes:- http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/